# MAMP does not display a window in which port settings can be changed

Tags: macos, mamp, ports

I have a new installation of MAMP.

I have tried to follow instructions for changing the ports, but the MAMP program does not give me an option to open preferences.

Screen shot

[image]

So, I can't get to a window to allow me to make the port changes within the MAMP program - unless someone knows better!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MAMP version `4.2.1` and the Preferences option is where your Cloud button is.

Can you get to preferences through top menu or by pressing `⌘,`?

[image: MAMP app menu]

Comment: Yes, in latest MAMP Preferences is available from the MAMP menu item!